# Dropdown multi-level menu in parallel

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown multilevel menu with the sublist in parallel, as the image:

[image: 1]

The sublist must be parallel and not diagonal, as is common in multilevel menus:

[image: 2].

If I use independent divs instead of sublist, I don't see how to tell to the subcategory div which parent category element is selected.

My try: https://codepen.io/Agrimensor/pen/vYgGJwr

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #0abf53;
}

.dropdown li {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown li ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown li ul li ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul li:hover > a {
  background-color: #0abf53;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Nice Dropdown Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Submenu - 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu - 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Like that? - https://ibb.co/F413Lp6

Comment: I think so. Like my first image.

Answer (score 1):

Remove rules `top: 0` and `left: 100%` in `.dropdown li ul`, and also remove `position: relative` from `.dropdown li`.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #0abf53;
}

.dropdown li {
    /* position: relative;*/
}

.dropdown li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown li ul {
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 0;
    left: 100%;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    line-height: normal;
    background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown li ul li a {
    text-align: left;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0abf53;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown li ul li ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #0abf53;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.dropdown:hover * {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown > li > ul:hover ul {
    display: none;
}

li:hover > a.drop + ul {
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Nice Dropdown Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="drop" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="drop" href="#">Dropdown</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu - 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu - 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu - 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be possible to make the three submenus display at once when hovering the "menu" button? The first time it should just show the sublist of the first element, and if I select the second element, it change the content of the sublist, etc.

Comment: @FiveString, I have updated the snippet. Is this the result you need?

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly. The first step is correct: shows the entire menu. But, if I have a sublist inside 'Nice Dropdown Menu', it should show its sublist in this first step; and if I have another sublist inside 'Submenu - 1' and I hover it, it should change the two sublist on the right to show the sublist of 'Submenu - 1'. It's a bit messy, sorry...

Comment: @FiveString, For a long time I could not understand what result you are describing. And it seems that he did not understand until now. But I updated my snippet. Do you need such a result?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion. This is what I want to achieve: https://codepen.io/Agrimensor/pen/vYgGJwr ... but with just CSS or at least without garbage JS.

(( Click Menu - Show -> 1 | 1.1 | 1.1.1 ))
(( Click 1.2 - Show -> 1 | 1.2 | 1.2.1 ))
(( Click 2 - Show -> 2 | 2.1 | 2.1.1 ))